# Passing arguments to AVA test files

Tags: node.js, typescript, playwright, ava, yargs

I'm looking for ways to pass arguments to my ava test file via command line and I found this documentation. https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/main/docs/recipes/passing-arguments-to-your-test-files.md

// test.js
const test = require('ava');

```
test('argv', t => {
    t.deepEqual(process.argv.slice(2), ['--hello', 'world']);
});

$ npx ava -- --hello world
```

I was wondering that what this code is actually doing but I can't find other related topic online talking about this. Is there anyone who can explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is just showing you that in node - and therefore also in `ava`, the arguments are available on the array `process.argv`. You can find it documented [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processargv)

The `slice(2)` just trims off the first two elements of the array. From the documentation I linked above, this is because:

> The first element will be process.execPath.

> The second element will be the path to the JavaScript file being
> executed

So your arguments start at `process.argv[2]`.

The `t.deepEqual` is just illustrative to show the reader that the value of `process.argv.slice(2)` is:

```
 ['--hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Now I have a better understanding on it.